# How to prevent resizing when mobile url hides

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

I know this has been discussed, and I have tried to implement the suggested  javascript fix for the problem, but it seems like nothing I do resolves it. Is there a definitive fix for mobile dropdown urls resizing fixed background images? Here is the JS I added to try and fix the problem:

```
$(function(){
  var bg = $("#about-page-background-image, #blogs-page-background-image, #blogs-page-background-image-show, #faqs-page-background-image, #whats-included-page-background-image");
  $(window).on('resize', resizeBackground);
  function resizeBackground() {
    var windowSize = $(window).height() + 60 + 'px';
    bg.css('height', windowSize);
  }
  resizeBackground();
})
```

This works, but not until you remove your finger from the screen, which doesn't help, there is still a 60px white space when I scroll up and the URL hides. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions, this has been bugging me for some time.

Comment: If you are testing on iOS, JS execution is paused while scrolling, so `resizeBackground` will not be allowed to run until the screen stops. (I'm afraid I don't know an alternative, but that's probably why your current solution isn't working)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am testing on iOS, I wasn't aware of the pause while scrolling, that explains a lot.